# In extjs4 how to call function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am working in Extjs4 and I am getting stuck at a point where I want to call a function inside another function.

Here I am going to call hideLoginWindow() function in success function.

How can I call hideLoginWindow() function inside success function. 
Here Is my controller file code

```
Ext.define('Am.controller.sn.UserController',
        {

            extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
            stores:['sn.UserStore','sn.SecurityquestionStore'],
            models:['sn.UserModel','sn.SecurityquestionModel'],
            views:['sn.user.Login','sn.user.Registration','sn.user.ForgetMyKey','sn.user.SecurityQuestion','sn.user.KpLogin'],


            init:function()
            {
                console.log('Initialized Users! This happens before the Application launch function is called'); 
                this.control(
                {
                    'Login button[action=loginAction]':
                    {
                        click:this.authenticateUser
                    },
                    'Login button[action=registerAction]':
                    {
                        click:this.registerUser
                    },
                    'KpLogin button[action=loginAction]':
                    {
                        click:this.authenticateUser 
                    }   
                });//end of this.control    
            },//end of init function    
    authenticateUser:function(button)
    {
        ***// this function is called
        this.temp();***

        var email=this.getUserName().getValue();
        var password=this.getPassword().getValue();
        console.log("Email"+email);
        console.log("Password"+password);
        var check = Ext.ModelManager.create(
        {
            primaryEmail:email,
            password: password,
        }, 'Am.model.sn.UserModel');
        check.save(
        {   
            success: function(record, operation) 
            {

                if(operation.request.scope.reader.jsonData["id"]==1)
                {
                    // Code for geting component
                    alert("you are logged in successfully");

                    **//this function is not called
                    this.hideLoginWindow(); // I tried also hideLoginWindow();**

                }//end of if statement


            },//End of success function
            failure: function(record, operation) 
            {
                console.log("Inside failure function");

            },//End of failure function

        });// End of check save function
        console.log("outside authenticated function");

    },//end of authenticate user function


    //***************************Reusable functions********************
    // this function get called
    temp:function()
    {
        console.log("Temp function called");
    },
    //this function is not get called
    hideLoginWindow:function()
    {
        var obj=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginId');
        console.log("Object name = "+obj[0].id);
        obj[0].hide();
    }
});// End of login controller
```

When I am running this code I get error which is

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hideLoginWindow'

How can I call hideLoginWindow() function inside success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scope of the save callbacks:

```
check.save({
    scope: this,
    success: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself, what is `this` at the point of your method call? Because that call is inside another function, the scope is now inside that function and not in the outer object where your `hideLoginWindow()` method resides.

The best thing to do is to set the scope of your `check.save` method before you call it...

```
check.save({
    scope: this,
    //...
});
```

This will retain the scope of the outer object when you enter your function call